# Website preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to create a website `preloader` with a logo. I would like to create the logo color filling preloading effect (something like water filling into a glass) or spinning the logo or anything (but the first technic is preferred ). It can be done with animated `gif` but, to get the actual effect (or less than actual), the `gif` file size will definitely be increased.

I found many `.gif` preloader, but those are not my exact requirement.

It may be done with `css/js/jquery`, but the problem is, I do not know how to start.

Can anybody help me ?

The logo is a `.png` image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use code from here: http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/
There are some great preloaders on pure css

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and the link. But If I want to get the above said `filling effect` what should I do ?